# How to use the extra params in ExtJS Upload Widget by Ivan Novakov

Tags: javascript, php, extjs, extjs4

I am using [this upload widget](https://github.com/ivan-novakov/extjs-upload-widget) in my web application.

I am using the `FormDataUploader` and I am able to upload files to a server directory quite well. However, I wanted to send extra parameters as well to the php file handling the upload. This is what I attempted:

```
var uploadPanel = Ext.create('Ext.ux.upload.Panel', {
    uploader : 'Ext.ux.upload.uploader.FormDataUploader',

    uploaderOptions : {
       url : 'uploadGallery.php'
    },

    synchronous : true,

    uploadParams : {
        ID_Person : ID_Person,
        ID_CI : ID_CI
    }

});
```

As you can see, I used the `uploadParams`, however, my PHP couldn't seem to receive it. In my php file, I have:

```
$ID_Person = $_GET['ID_Person'];
$ID_CI = $_GET['ID_CI'];
```

However, my PHP seems to be unable to get these params.

What I did next was to use the default ExtJS Uploader as such:

```
var uploadPanel = Ext.create('Ext.ux.upload.Panel', {
    uploaderOptions : {
        url : 'uploadExtJS.php'

    },

    synchronous : true,

    uploadParams : {
        ID_Person : ID_Person,
        ID_CI : ID_CI
    }

});
```

At first, I used the old PHP file which was able to get the extra params I sent. However, it seems that I needed to use a different PHP file for the ExtJS uploader.

This is what my PHP file looks like:

```
<?php
/**
 * Example processing of raw PUT/POST uploaded files.
 * File metadata may be sent through appropriate HTTP headers:
 *   - file name - the 'X-File-Name' proprietary header
 *   - file size - the standard 'Content-Length' header or the 'X-File-Size' proprietary header
 *   - file type - the standard 'Content-Type' header or the 'X-File-Type' proprietary header
 * 
 * Raw data are read from the standard input.
 * The response should be a JSON encoded string with these items:
 *   - success (boolean) - if the upload has been successful
 *   - message (string) - optional message, useful in case of error
 */
require __DIR__ . '_common.php';
$config = require __DIR__ . '_config.php';

error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

/*
 * You should check these values for XSS or SQL injection.
 */
if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_NAME'])) {
    _error('Unknown file name');
}
$fileName = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_NAME'];
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILENAME_ENCODER']) && 'base64' == $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILENAME_ENCODER']) {
    $fileName = base64_decode($fileName);
}
$fileName = htmlspecialchars($fileName);

$mimeType = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_TYPE']);
$size = intval($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_SIZE']);


$inputStream = fopen('php://input', 'r');
// $outputFilename = $config['upload_dir'] . '/' . $fileName;
$outputFilename = 'gallery' . '/' . $fileName;
$realSize = 0;
$data = '';

if ($inputStream) {
    if (! $config['fake']) {
        $outputStream = fopen($outputFilename, 'w');
        if (! $outputStream) {
            _error('Error creating local file');
        }
    }

    while (! feof($inputStream)) {
        $bytesWritten = 0;
        $data = fread($inputStream, 1024);

        if (! $config['fake']) {
            $bytesWritten = fwrite($outputStream, $data);
        } else {
            $bytesWritten = strlen($data);
        }

        if (false === $bytesWritten) {
            _error('Error writing data to file');
        }
        $realSize += $bytesWritten;
    }

    if (! $config['fake']) {
        fclose($outputStream);
    }
} else {
    _error('Error reading input');
}

if ($realSize != $size) {
    _error('The actual size differs from the declared size in the headers');
}

_log(sprintf("[raw] Uploaded %s, %s, %d byte(s)", $fileName, $mimeType, $realSize));
_response();
```

However, I am getting an Internal Server 500 Error - Meaning that there was something probably wrong with my php file.

I mainly have two questions:

1. How do I make the uploadParams work with the FormDataUploader?
2. How do I write a PHP uploader for an ExtJS Data Uploader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work.

The uploadExtJS.php file should look like:

```
<?php
/**
 * Example processing of raw PUT/POST uploaded files.
 * File metadata may be sent through appropriate HTTP headers:
 *   - file name - the 'X-File-Name' proprietary header
 *   - file size - the standard 'Content-Length' header or the 'X-File-Size' proprietary header
 *   - file type - the standard 'Content-Type' header or the 'X-File-Type' proprietary header
 * 
 * Raw data are read from the standard input.
 * The response should be a JSON encoded string with these items:
 *   - success (boolean) - if the upload has been successful
 *   - message (string) - optional message, useful in case of error
 */
// require  __DIR__ . '_common.php';
// $config = require  __DIR__ .  '_config.php';

require_once '_common.php';
$config = require_once '_config.php';

error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

/*
 * You should check these values for XSS or SQL injection.
 */
if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_NAME'])) {
    _error('Unknown file name');
}
$fileName = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_NAME'];
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILENAME_ENCODER']) && 'base64' == $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILENAME_ENCODER']) {
    $fileName = base64_decode($fileName);
}
$fileName = htmlspecialchars($fileName);

$mimeType = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_TYPE']);
$size = intval($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_SIZE']);


$inputStream = fopen('php://input', 'r');
$outputFilename = $config['upload_dir'] . '/' . $fileName;
// $outputFilename = 'gallery' . '/' . $fileName;
$realSize = 0;
$data = '';

if ($inputStream) {
    if (! $config['fake']) {
        $outputStream = fopen($outputFilename, 'w');
        if (! $outputStream) {
            _error('Error creating local file');
        }
    }

    while (! feof($inputStream)) {
        $bytesWritten = 0;
        $data = fread($inputStream, 1024);

        if (! $config['fake']) {
            $bytesWritten = fwrite($outputStream, $data);
        } else {
            $bytesWritten = strlen($data);
        }

        if (false === $bytesWritten) {
            _error('Error writing data to file');
        }
        $realSize += $bytesWritten;
    }

    if (! $config['fake']) {
        fclose($outputStream);
    }
} else {
    _error('Error reading input');
}

if ($realSize != $size) {
    _error('The actual size differs from the declared size in the headers');
}

_log(sprintf("[raw] Uploaded %s, %s, %d byte(s)", $fileName, $mimeType, $realSize));
_response(true, "okay");
```

_common.php looks like:

```
<?php

function _log($value){
    error_log(print_r($value, true));
}


function _response($success = true, $message = 'OK'){
    $response = array(
        'success' => $success,
        'message' => $message
    );

    echo json_encode($response);
    exit();
}

function _error($message){
    return _response(false, $message);
}
```

_config.php should look like:

```
<?php
return array(
    'upload_dir' => 'gallery',
    'fake' => false
);
?>
```

and now I'm working on using a unique name using `uniqid()` and `microtime()`, as well as saving the images to a subdirectory (or any folder under your main upload/gallery folder) using the `uploadParams()` property.

**EDIT 1: RENAMING THE UPLOADED FILE**

just change this line:

```
$fileName = htmlspecialchars($fileName);
```

to:

```
$fileName = uniqid() . '_' . microtime();
```

**EDIT 3: TO GET THE CUSTOM SUB DIRECTORY FROM YOUR ADDITIONAL PARAMS**

First, make sure than when you create your Upload Dialog from your ExtJS web app, you do this:

```
var uploadPanel = Ext.create('Ext.ux.upload.Panel', {
    uploaderOptions : {
        url : 'uploadExtJS.php'

    },
    synchronous : true,
    uploadParams : {
        ID_1 : ID_1,
        ID_2 : ID_2 // you can put waaay more if you want
    }
});
```

and in your uploadExtJS.php, do this (between the part where you define your new file name and the part where you check for input stream)

```
$fileName = uniqid() . '_' . microtime();

$mimeType = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_TYPE']);
$size = intval($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_SIZE']);

$ID_1 = $_GET['ID_1'];
$ID_2 = $_GET['ID_2'];

$newFilePath = $config['upload_dir'] . '/' . $ID_1 . '/' . $ID_2;

if (!file_exists($newFilePath)) {
    mkdir($newFilePath, 0777, true);
}

$inputStream = fopen('php://input', 'r');
$outputFilename = $newFilePath . '/' . $fileName;

$realSize = 0;
$data = '';
```

As you can see, I defined a `$newFilePath` variable, checked if it was existing before making it, then uploaded to that directory.

Hope this helps anyone who encounters the issue in the future.